# AppleScript - IF trackpad button is down statement

Tags: applescript, trackpad

I'd like to know if it's possible (in AppleScript) to tell the difference between trackpad buton-down and trackpad button-up.

I'm trying to create a preset in ControllerMate to emporarily toggle the functionality of the trackpad click (button 1 - "left click") with another functionality (button 2 - "middle click").

This is my progress so far:

[image: Gif]

Thank you!